# What is the goal of studying all those NP-complete problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete

So i'm currently reading a lot of things about graph NP-complete problems, and it seems that the goal of a lot of researchers is to find new results about their complexity, results like "independent set is 1.593 approximable for graphs which doesn't contains K4 K5 P3 as a minor" (this is probably a wrong result i just invented something which looks like a result we could find in a paper), approximation algorithms, parameterized complexity etc ...

But i'm wondering : what really is the goal to study independent set, vertex cover, hamiltonian circuit etc ... ? Do they have real case application ? Is there any software that uses independent set algorithms ?

Or is it only for the theory ? To discover something new in the P vs NP problems ?

To sum up : are NP-complete problems (and i'm particularly interested in NP-complete graph problems) useful in the reality ?

PS : sorry if the title may seem offensive, it is not, i know a lot of searchers study things which does not have much applications in reality, i want to know if it is the case for np-complete problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No one are offended by that question, and it's an important question to
ask.

When working in graph theory, we don't believe that proving hardness
results for independent set on $\{K_4, K_5, P_3\}$-minor-free graphs are
"important".  However, it is interesting to see *why* a certain
forbidden minor puts a problem from being, e.g. polynomial time
solvable, to NP-complete.  It is then important that *that* is the
focus.

Here is an interesting problem:

> Does edge deletion to claw-free graphs admit a polynomial kernel?

Why is it interesting?  Because we know almost everything else about
kernels and edge deletion to $H$-free graphs.  This one is interesting
because it is notoriously hard.  And hopefully, once this is solved, we
will understand more about the interplay between $H$-free graphs, edge
deletion, and polynomial kernels.

But I want to also mention that, yes, there are indeed applications that use algorithms for independent set, vertex cover, travelling salesman, etc.   See for example [Dependency hell is NP-complete](https://research.swtch.com/version-sat).

---

Fast forward to *industry*.  After quitting academia and joining
industry as a developer, I have more than once been able to tell people
that what they are working on is NP-complete, and to provide insight
into a problem that I got from studying these problems in a theoretic
setting.

I have written and published my share of "unusable" algorithms, but it's
not expected that people can take algorithms and plug-and-play them into
their system.  What they *can* take is the insight we provide in
structures, heuristics, as well as hardness.  Sometimes a problem is
only hard on graphs that have large grids as minors, and if you suddenly
see that your data is "tree-like", then you might have some tricks to
share with your future industry-colleagues.

Comment: What is a problem that is only hard on graphs that have large grids as minors?

Comment: @alphacapture This was written three years ago, I don't know exactly what I was thinking, but I was probably thinking about problems on planar graphs that admit fast algorithms on bounded treewidth graphs.